# iPhone SDK: building app for AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have dev cert and distibution cert. I am able to build an app to run on my own device and also followed Apple's instuctions to build for AppStore by using Distribution Cert. I also followed Apple's guidance to verify that app was correctly signed by reviewing a build log.

However I still have a question. Consider the following screen shot: http://www.braginski.com/temp.jpg

There are TWO entires: one which correctly say "Don't code sign" and the second which points to my distribution certificate.

All Apple docs show the first box as EMPTY and second box with the acctual cetificate.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make first box empty.

So the question is: what should the first box be? Does it even matter? Build log shows that app is signed even when first box says "Don't sign"

thanks

Comment: "the following screen shot" is now a 404. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to have the default setting, just press delete key on this setting, it will give you the default.

"The first box" is only a automatic setter for the "second box". It is actually important to choose carefully the "second box" (and the first one if you want it to choose automatically) because it chooses in with which distribution profile you're signing with.

If you build logs shows that it's singing anyway, be sure that you're changing the configuration you want to actually change.

[image]

Comment: This explains it, thanks!!! It did appear that first box does not really change the effect of signing, but the second one it the key.

I hope having Dont Sign did not screw up anything in the app submissions, but I will know soon enouhg. If yes, I will make sure to hit Delete key and only use second box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear that value, just select it with the mouse and press your delete key.

I have always left it empty when building for AppStore distribution, so I can't tell you what the effect would be of leaving it in Don't Sign.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have confirmed that having "Don't code sign" in the first box of have empty first box is THE SAME thing as long as certificate in the second box is selected correctly.

I ran two builds with and without "Don't code sign" in the first box. I saved both build results as a text files and compared them.

These files are identical, which leads me to believe that as was pointed out by Gcamp the first box must be just a method of selecting a default for the second both. Very strange UI in XCode if you ask me.